# Definiteness and indefiniteness

Tags: terminology, definiteness

Is there a term that encompasses both terms at once? Suppose I am writing a paper titled **[Single-word-here] in Language X**, where the required word will refer to both definiteness and indefiniteness. Or is it the case that a title such as **Definiteness in Language X** does that job?

Comment: Yes, 'definiteness' is the name of the area that deals with definites, indefinites, etc. Eg this publication ["Definiteness across languages"](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/227) and the papers therein.

Comment: See also WALS, Chapter [37 "Definite Articles"](https://wals.info/chapter/37) and Chapter [38 "Indefinite Articles"](https://wals.info/chapter/38).